# Angular.js unit test controller with others modules dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Background:

I have an angular.js controller 'GetResultController' with some external dependencies:

```
angular.module('data-service',[]).service('DataService', DataService);

angular.module('GetResultModule', ['datatables', 'data-service']);
angular.module('GetResultModule')
       .controller('GetResultController',
       ['$q','DTColumnBuilder','DataService', GetResultController]);

function GetResultController($q, DTColumnBuilder, DataService) {
    let self = this;
    self.getResult = function getResult() {
        return 'positive';
    }
}
```

Questions:

ver-1:

```
describe('testGetResultController', () =>{
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('datatable');
    //do i need to create the mock module for 'data-service', and how to do next? 
    }
)
```

ver-2:

```
describe('testGetResultController', () => {
    beforeEach(angular.module('datatable',[]);
    beforeEach(angular.module('common-service',[]);
    let c;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_) {
      c = _$controller_('GetResultController'); // is it correct to get back the controller?
    }
    it('test', ()=> {
      expect(c).toBeDefined(); // why c is undefined?
    });
})
```

As I want to draft a unit test to verify 'GetResultController'. How can I initialize the dependencies, mock the object to test the 'getResult' method.  Do we have any experience to handle this case.

Many thanks

Comment: The controller under test is part of the module GetResultModule. So that's the module you need to load using angular.mock.module(). Not the datatable module. Then you can create your controller instance using $controller and test it. But since it doen't contain anything other than an inner function that is not reachable from the outside, there's not much to test.

Comment: Yes, the GetResultController is minised and there are others methods included in this controller. I want to grap the concept on how to set up the unit test for a controller with external dependencies. JB, could you share some code for my reference, your comment is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about you trying to do it, following the indications I already gave you?

Comment: Do you mean that i just only need to load the 'GetResultModule' - angular.module('GetResultModule,[]) in the beforeEach phrase. And, I read an reference online: https://www.sitepoint.com/unit-testing-angularjs-services-controllers-providers/. Is this approach fit my case.

Comment: No. That's not what I said. That would redefine a new, empty module, named GetResultModule. I told you "that's the module you need to load using angular.mock.module()". So you need `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('GetResultModule'));`.